# Appium capability baseUrl is not working when trying to connect to remote server

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am trying to run my tests with a remote Appium server. Until now, I have always used the server in the same machine where the tests are being run, so I was using url + port (localhost:4723).

The problem I am facing now is that the "baseUrl" capability does not make any change, it seems that it is being ignored. I am using Appium 1.22.3

This is my code:

```
const url = '88.123.123.23'
const path = '/ws/hub';
const timeout = 20000;

export function createAndroidConfig(port: number, deviceName: string, id: string): RemoteOptions {
    const config: RemoteOptions = {
        path: path,
        port: port,
        logLevel: 'trace',
        baseUrl: url,
        waitforTimeout: timeout,
        capabilities: {
            udid: id,
            automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
            platformName: 'Android',
            deviceName: deviceName,
            autoGrantPermissions: true,
            unicodeKeyboard: true,
            resetKeyboard: true,
            'appium:app': apkPath,
            newCommandTimeout: 100000,
            unlockType: "pin",
            unlockKey: "0000"
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

The error I get:

```
Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/ws/hub", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
```

I have searched for it, thinking it could be an Appium bug, but I did not find information.

If I change the port or path, the changes do take effect, but url does not.

Answer (score 0):

const path = '/ws/hub';

/wd/hub
replace this with

Comment: i was using /wd/hub, i changed it to see if that capability would apply, and yes. But the baseUrl is not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).